# List of methods in iOS that have been deprecated for security reasons?

Tags: mobile, ios, static-analysis

Is anybody on the nets keeping track of iOS methods that have been deprecated by Apple for security reasons? I have searched around but with no luck.

Going through all the deprecated methods and figuring out which ones have security implications would/will be a lot of work. I'm hoping this info is already being tracked elsewhere. 
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793311/does-anyone-know-which-methods-are-deprecated-in-ios-6-0

Answer (score 2):

This may be of some help. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5567

I would think this information would be in the Security Update announcement.

Comment: That's an interesting link, but I don't see any information in it on deprecated methods.  I would not expect Security Updates to contain a list of deprecated methods; Software Updates tend to be written for a user audience, not for developers.

Comment: I did find lists of deprecated methods in the iOS library on Apple's developer website, but they didn't say if they are deprecated for security reasons.